# SSRS Date Calculation - Case?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, case

```
DATEDIFF(D, dbo.Sum_ProductionPersonnel.LastLeaverDate, dbo.Sum_ProductionPersonnel.HRMSStartDate) AS DaysBetweenLastLeaverAndStartDate
```

This is a calculation in my query which i want to use in SSRS.

In my SSRS table i would like the formula to show

```
IF DaysBetweenLastLeaverAndStartDate < 0 Show N/A
Else Show days
```

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

Use the whole function in both parts of the `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(D, dbo.Sum_ProductionPersonnel.LastLeaverDate, dbo.Sum_ProductionPersonnel.HRMSStartDate) < 0 
THEN 'N/A' 
ELSE DATEDIFF(D, dbo.Sum_ProductionPersonnel.LastLeaverDate, dbo.Sum_ProductionPersonnel.HRMSStartDate) 
END as DaysBetweenLastLeaverAndStartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this similarly in the text box's **expression** using an **IIF** statement:

```
=IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Fields!LastLeaverDate.Value, Fields!HRMSStartDate.Value) < 0, "N/A", DATEDIFF("d", Fields!LastLeaverDate.Value, Fields!HRMSStartDate.Value))
```